# $h:[0,1] \to\mathbb{R}$ continuous, and ivt

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, continuity

The question is as follows:
$$ \text{Supposd } h:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{ is continuous. Show that there exist } w \in [0,1] \text{ such that}
\\h(w)= \frac{w+1}{2}h(0)+\frac{2w+2}{9}h(\frac{1}{2})+\frac{w+1}{12}h(1)$$

I know that I have to use Intermediate Value Theorem and I have to show $h(w)$ lies between $h(0)$ and $h(1)$, but I have no idea how to prove it.

I have tried to separate $h(w)$ into $\frac{w+1}{2}h(0)+\frac{w+1}{9}h(\frac12)+\frac{w+1}{9}h(\frac12)+\frac{w+1}{12}h(1)$ and then use IVT twice on the interval $[0,\frac12]$ and $[\frac12,1]$ but it seems not working. I have also tried to see if $h$ is an interpolation of 3 points but it also fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let  $f(x)=\frac {h(x)}{(x+1)}$ which is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $T=1/2f(0)+1/3f(1/2)+1/6f(1)$.

Then we want to prove ,$$f(w)=T \ \ \text{for some } \ w\in [0,1]$$

Let $M$ and $m$ be maximum and minimum value taken by $f(x)$.

Then note that, $m\leq T\leq M$.

Comment: You glossed over the conversion of the RHS to be in terms of $f$: the point is that $1/2 h(0)=(1) \cdot (1/2 f(0)),2/9 h(1/2)=(3/2) \cdot 2/9 f(0)$ and $1/12 h(0)=(2) \cdot 1/12 f(0)$, where the quantities in parentheses are $w+1$ evaluated at $0,1/2$ and $1$. IMO noting that this results in a convex combination of $f(0),f(1/2)$ and $f(1)$ is the core of puzzling out this question; if the problem were already given as a convex combination then it would be significantly more obvious what to do.

Comment: @Ian I don't see any mistake?May be Im missing something? Can you be more specific

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just not fully clear from your writeup why $T$ is what it is. You need to do a little arithmetic to see how the coefficients $1/2,2/9,1/12$ turn into $1/2,1/3,1/6$.

Comment: Also it is instructive to point out that this answer generalizes in a straightforward way: if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i f(x_i)$ has a solution for any set of numbers $x_i \in [a,b]$ and positive numbers $c_i$ summing to $1$. The key point is that they sum to exactly $1$. Basically any weighted average of some function values is attained at some point in the domain. But if the weights don't sum to exactly $1$ then there is always some counterexample (for example if $f(x_i)=M$ for all $i$).

Answer (score 3):

Let $d(w)=h(w)- \bigg(\frac{w+1}{2}h(0)+\frac{2w+2}{9}h(\frac{1}{2})+\frac{w+1}{12}h(1) \bigg)$.

Then,

$$
18d(0)+8d(\frac{1}{2})+3d(1)=0
$$

So the numbers $d(0),d(\frac{1}{2}),d(1)$, if all nonzero, are not all of the same sign. Can you finish from here ?

Comment: This was basically the approach that I thought to try at first but I didn't realize how to correctly incorporate the $w+1$ factor to get a vector in the left null space of the relevant matrix (which is effectively what this $(18,8,3)$ is). When you naively write the coefficients without taking the $w+1$ correctly into account, you end up with invertible matrices.

Comment: To clarify what I mean about the left null space, the point is that $\begin{bmatrix} d(0) \\ d(1/2) \\ d(1) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & -2/9 & -1/12 \\ -3/4 & 2/3 & -1/8 \\ -1 & -4/9 & 5/6 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} h(0) \\ h(1/2) \\ h(1) \end{bmatrix}$. We hope to argue that $d(0),d(1/2),d(1)$ can't all be of the same nonzero sign by finding $a,b,c$ with $ad(0)+bd(1/2)+cd(1)=0$, without the freedom to choose $h(0),h(1/2),h(1)$.

Comment: (Cont.) This means we need $a,b,c$ to form a nonzero vector in the left null space of $\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & -2/9 & -1/12 \\ -3/4 & 2/3 & -1/8 \\ -1 & -4/9 & 5/6 \end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix} 18 & 8 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$ is in that left null space.

Comment: @Ian Exactly. Thanks for completing my answer